# TeXShop - Latex to html

Tags: html, macos, latex

I am trying to make a website based on a report I wrote in LaTeX. Is there a way to convert a latex file to html using TeXShop, or do I have to install MacTeX?

Comment: Great! Problem solved. The commands to convert a .tex into an html file are available here:http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115033/latex-to-html-using-pandoc.

Comment: @albus_c Hi! Please consider marking the answer as accepted, or write a new one and accept it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Despite [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/) is capable to convert from several markups to a wide range of formats (including EPUB), one more specific tool to cite here is Perl-based [LaTeX2HTML](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/latex2html).

One advantage of the first over the second is that, as of 2015, only Pandoc can be set to convert to HTML5 standards, while LaTeX2HTML was last updated in 1999. Anyway this can be a big issue or not since, in my experience, *all* converted documents need *some* human work before they reach their final shape.

Pandoc and LaTeX2HTML work on Windows and Mac OS but, in both cases, MacTeX is not required.